# ImageView Tilt effect onTouch

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-animation

I want to show tilt (pressed) effect by x degree on an ImageView where ever user touches on the image.

any Idea how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
    final ObjectAnimator forwardAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView,
            "RotationX", 0, 20f);
    forwardAnimator.setDuration(250);
    final ObjectAnimator backwardAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView,
            "RotationX", 20f, 0f);
    backwardAnimator.setStartDelay(250);
    backwardAnimator.setDuration(250);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            forwardAnimator.start();
            backwardAnimator.start();
        }
    });
```

This requries API level 11...because the ObjectAnimator supports from Api level 11